# Check-in trouble with Team Explorer Everywhere

Tags: tfs, xamarin.ios, terminal, xamarin-studio, team-explorer-everywhere

Using TFS and the wonderful Team Explorer Everywhere command line tool on a mac. 
I have managed to do the following:

--Created a profile
--Created a workspace(mapping between the TFS folders and my machine folders)
--Was able to "get" my teams project

```
sudo tf get * MyProjectName
```

--Was able to checkout my teams project

```
sudo tf checkout MyProjectName -recursive -lock:none
```

Now when i try to edit .cs files with my IDE, Xamarin-studio, it won't save them back. It says an error has occurred.
The error message:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
"/Users/ingimarbjarnason/Applicon/Vigor/MiniOrka.iOS/.#ActionSheetPicker.cs" is denied.
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x0032f] in
/private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin-no-pcl/build-root/mono-
3.2.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:320 
.....
```

It's like the file is locked and Xamarin-Studio won't change it.
Has anyone used these two together and knows how to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using TFS on Mac for a bit and it has the same problem that I have using Xamarin Studio with TFS on windows. 
The files are in a read-only state (which with VS this works fine). I manually change them to read/write.

There is probably a better way but they(IT) won't let me setup an SVN bridge to use TFS from within Xamarin Studio. ....

Also side note the Eclipse plugin for TFS works great and gives you all the functionality you have in VS; I recommend switching from just the command line tool.